# Select only one from optgroup options in multiselect drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have drop down like this

```
<select multiple="multiple">
 <optgroup label='name1'>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label='name2'>
   <option value="1">First</option>
   <option value="2">Second</option>
   <option value="3">Third</option>
 </optgroup> 
<select>
```

This is multiselect drop down,But i should select only one option from each optgroup options.

Eg. If option "First" is selected for 'name1' then "second","third" should not be selectable for 'name1' optgroup options.

Comment: Do refer to my answer if you want to do what you require without disabling elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var memoryOne;
var memoryTwo;
$("option").mouseover(function () {
    var selectedOne = $("optgroup:nth-of-type(1)").children("option:selected").index();
    var selectedTwo = $("optgroup:nth-of-type(2)").children("option:selected").index();
    memoryOne = selectedOne;
    memoryTwo = selectedTwo;
}).click(function () {
    var theSelectedIndex = $(this).index();
    var theParentIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    setTimeout(function () {
        clickEvent(theSelectedIndex, theParentIndex, memoryOne, memoryTwo);
    }, 1);
});

function clickEvent(passedIndex, parentIndex, memoryOne, memoryTwo) {
    var selectionOne = memoryOne;
    var selectionTwo = memoryTwo;
    var theParent = $("optgroup:eq(" + parentIndex + ")");
    var theOption = $("optgroup:eq(" + parentIndex + ") option:eq(" + passedIndex + ")");
    var theGrandParent = $("select");
    theParent.find("option:not(option:eq(" + passedIndex + "))").prop("selected", false);

    if (parentIndex == 0) {
        $("optgroup:not(optgroup:eq(" + parentIndex + "))").children("option:eq(" + selectionTwo + ")").prop("selected", true);
    } else if (parentIndex == 1) {
        $("optgroup:not(optgroup:eq(" + parentIndex + "))").children("option:eq(" + selectionOne + ")").prop("selected", true);
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/thauwa/ee8VH/

Comment: The above code has redundancies and uses bad programming practices, so any potential user might have to clean it. I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Try radios instead!

```
<form name="myform">
    <div align="center">
        <input type="radio" name="name1" value="First" />First<br />
        <input type="radio" name="name1" value="Second" />Second<br />
        <input type="radio" name="name1" value="Third" />Third

        <hr>

        <input type="radio" name="name2" value="First" /> First<br />
        <input type="radio" name="name2" value="Second" /> Second<br />
        <input type="radio" name="name2" value="Third" /> Third
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('select optgroup option').click(function () {
    var len = $(this).parent().find(':selected').length
    if (len > 1) {
        alert('only 1 allowed')
        $(this).prop('selected', false)
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3Dhn/3/)

Comment: Here is another code disabling selecting more than 1 item under a group without showing any alert (this behavior may annoy some users) http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/d3Dhn/7/

Comment: @KingKing in that multiple option in sigle group possible check with code

Comment: what do you mean? what's wrong with my version? as I understand your code does the similar thing, even without showing an alert, user can still see the clicked item selected and deselected right back (caused by `$(this).prop('selected', false)`).

Answer (score 1):

A multiselect is intended to allow multiple selections whereas a standard list/menu allows only a single selection.  Try:

```
<select name="name1" id="name1">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
<select name="name2" id="name2">
    <option value="First">First</option>
    <option value="Second">Second</option>
    <option value="Third">Third</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to disable rest option afte select one:

```
$("select").on("change",
                   function(){
                        $(this).find("option:selected").parent().attr("disabled",true);
                    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9PjD/9/)